# intrinsic weak-reference vs. non-intrinsic weak-reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
@interface ....
/* will be the next 'runningScene' in the next frame
     nextScene is a weak reference. */
    CCScene *nextScene_;
@end
@implementation .......
-(void) replaceScene: (CCScene*) scene
{
    NSAssert( scene != nil, @"Argument must be non-nil");

    NSUInteger index = [scenesStack_ count];

    sendCleanupToScene_ = YES;
    [scenesStack_ replaceObjectAtIndex:index-1 withObject:scene];
    nextScene_ = scene; // nextScene_ is a weak ref
}

- (void) pushScene: (CCScene*) scene
{
    NSAssert( scene != nil, @"Argument must be non-nil");

    sendCleanupToScene_ = NO;

    [scenesStack_ addObject: scene];
    nextScene_ = scene; // nextScene_ is a weak ref
}
@end
```

those days i 'm fun with a ported cocos2d on ubuntu (named cocostep). i found some funny things while  i dig into cocos2d source of "CCdirector.m" and observing several point commented by "it is weak reference" . for my knowledge of objective-c,ios,osx. a ref is weak that must preceding by __weak keyword,but i did not foud any  around the whole project, indeed. so i guess it is somewhat non-intrinsic weak-reference,just strategies of cocos2d designer .according to my assumption. if some variable as weak reference(non-intrinsic) get release called,and deallocing its memory somewhere else , so subsequent call on this reference would be failed, even crash because the reference's value is not nil but invalid reference to that memory. in oder to work with the strategies properly, must i manually reset that variable to nil. is my speculation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your speculation is right.

Cocos2d doesn't use ARC so when they say `weak` it's not `weak` in a proper ARC-wise sense.

The correct terminology for those variables would be `unsafe_unretained`, which means not retained **and** not automatically nullified.

Such variables may be dangling pointers, therefore you'd better take care of that and manually nullify them as soon as possible.

Comment: hi, @Gabriele Petronella. thanks. i googled a link:   :http://shapeof.com/archives/2011/08/10.7_s_zeroing_weak_refs.html                  the article referring native-weak-reference api is built-weak mechanism for ARC. right?

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d does not use ARC. Any reference marked as weak in comments is a non-retaining reference. This means the reference may point to invalid memory if the reference gets deallocated and isn't manually set to nil.

Comment: hi @LearnCocos2D,yes cocos2d does not use arc.so i think it's some design strategies ,and it should be manually set to nil myself as ARC automaticaly does , in case of send message to it after it gets deallocated.

Comment: You could check out MAZeroingWeakRef by Mike Ash https://github.com/mikeash/MAZeroingWeakRef

Comment: @nielsbot thank your replay.could you please tell me what about  essential difference between ARC and arc.m(from libobjc2).is it ARC __weak specifier  work on top of native weak ref api?